# Designing in React: avoid using redux store to propagate data from child to parent component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am having issues finding the best way to organize my data / redux store for the following case:

I want to display a table that shows a list of users.  Above the table is a TableHelper component that contains among other features, a 'Filter' form (allows me to filter the list of users based on some search text).

In the code below, I have a Table component that takes a data array as props, and displays one row per element.
The table helper component takes the datasource (all the users), filters it based on the search text, and stores the resulting filtered list in the store, as `store.tableHelper.data`

The table, on the other hand, renders the filtered data if it exists, and if no filter was applied, just renders the entire data.

This approach has many flaws, as the table helper component can be used with multiple tables across applications, or possibly on the same page. In fact, it would probably be preferable to keep the filtered list out of the store entirely. The only obstacle preventing me from doing that is, the filtered list is computed inside the TableHelper component, and must somehow get returned to the parent container (whose code is below) that feeds the filtered list to the Table.

Any thoughts if it is possible to bypass the use of the store in this case? Or better yet, what would be a better approach to design a solution for this problem, given the following constraints:

- keep the TableHelper as its own component, for better reusability
- avoid polluting the store with a filtered list for each table

Code:

```
@connect((store) => {
  return {
    users: store.user.users,
    filteredData: store.tableHelper.data
  }
})
export default class Users extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(user.getAllUsers());
  }

  render() {
    const sourceData = _.map(this.props.users, function(user, i) {
      return {
        'name': user.fullName,
        'email' : user.email,
        'key': i
      }
    })

    // tableData shows the filtered data if such data is defined
    // otherwise, tableData is the source data
    let tableData = this.props.filteredData;

    if (!this.props.filteredData) {
      tableData = sourceData;
    }

    return (
      <div>
        <TableHelper data={sourceData}/> 
        <Table tableData={tableData} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a callback to the child as a prop, then when your TableHelper component have the filtered data ready it could just pass the info to that callback. You will probably want to have it as a component state inside your parent component so it updates automatically when you pass the filtered data, something like:

```
@connect((store) => {
  return {
    users: store.user.users
  }
})
export default class Users extends React.Component {

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.dispatch(user.getAllUsers());
  }

  // Callback that will be passed to the TableHelper component.
  handleFiltered = (data) => {
    this.setState({
      filteredData: data
    });
  }

  render() {
    const sourceData = _.map(this.props.users, function(user, i) {
      return {
        'name': user.fullName,
        'email' : user.email,
        'key': i
      }
    })

    // tableData shows the filtered data if such data is defined
    // otherwise, tableData is the source data
    tableData = this.state.filtered ? this.state.filtered : sourceData;

    return (
      <div>
        <TableHelper data={sourceData} updateFiltered={this.handleFiltered} /> 
        <Table tableData={tableData} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

That way, instead of updating the Redux store in your TableHelper component, you would use the callback to pass the data back to it's parent.

Comment: Thanks, this is much cleaner!